# FasterCSV: Check whether a file is invalid before accepting it - is there a simpler way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, fastercsv

I'm using FasterCSV on a Ruby on Rails application and currently it throws an Exception if the file is invalid.

I've looked over the [FasterCSV doc](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/), and it seems that if I use [FasterCSV::parse](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html#M000013) with a block, it'll read the file one line at a time, without allocating too much memory. It'll throw a [FasterCSV::MalformedCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV/MalformedCSVError.html) exception if there is any kind of error on the file.

I've implemented a custom solution, but I'm not sure it's the best possible one (see my answer below). I'd be interested in knowing alternatives

Comment: Two changes: 1) You need `def self.is_valid?` 2) Remove the superfluous `return` calls. Posted as a comment instead of an answer because you already basically have this answer, and I don't want to discourage additional answers. I suggest that you should remove your own code from the question and post it as an answer after some time has passed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've fixed my code (I prefer being explicit about return when it's not at the end of a method)

Comment: @egarcia How about `begin; parse{ ... }; true; rescue; false; end`

Comment: @Phrogz As a rubyist, I'm a big fan of one-liners. But ... please don't take it the wrong way, but I don't really like that semicolon business. On this particular case I think I'd rather be explicit about what is happening, even if the method spans several lines.

Comment: @egarcia To be clear, the semi-colons are only because I can't type newlines in comments. Anyhow, only a suggestion for what I consider to be more Ruby-like code.

Comment: @Phrogz ooh, I see what you mean now. You are right, it's more Ruby-like. I'm updating my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests yesterday and it turns out that my solution didn't quite work; I kept getting empty arrays on valid CSVs after implementing the first `is_valid` . I'm not sure whether it's a FasterCSV caching issue or something in my code, and I don't know if it's related with my test setup, but I decided to go implement a `safe_parse` instead:

```
#/lib/faster_csv_safe_parse.rb
class FasterCSV

  def self.safe_parse(file, options = {})
    begin
      FasterCSV.parse(file, options)
    rescue FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

This will return a parsed array if the file is valid, or `nil` otherwise. I could then implement my validations as follows:

```
# /models/csv_importer.rb

class CsvImporter
  include ActiveRecord::Validations

  validates_presence_of :file
  validate check_file_format
  attr_accessor csv_data

  def csv_data
    @csv_data ||= FasterCSV.safe_parse(file)
  end

...

  private

  def check_file_format
    errors.add :file, "Malformed CSV! Please check syntax" if csv_data.nil?
  end
end
```

I guess it would be possible to implement a `safe_parse` that accepts a block and parses the file line by line, but for my purposes this simple implementation was enough, and it works in all cases.

Comment: why not delete your previous answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution. I'm really interested in knowing improvements / alternatives.

```
# /lib/fastercsv_is_valid.rb

class FasterCSV

  def self.is_valid?(file, options = {})
    begin
      FasterCSV.parse(file, options) { |row| }
      true
    rescue FasterCSV::MalformedCSV
      false
    end
  end

end
```

I use that method like this:

```
# /models/csv_importer.rb

class CsvImporter
  include ActiveRecord::Validations

  validates_presence_of :file
  validate check_file_format

...

  private

  def check_file_format
    errors.add :file, "Malformed CSV! Please check syntax" unless FasterCSV::is_valid? file
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to parse the CSV and do something with the parsed results. Worst case is that your CSV is valid and that you parse the file again. I would write something like this to stash away the parsed result so you only have to parse the CSV once:

```
module FasterCSV

  def self.parse_and_validate(file, options = {})

    begin
      @parsed_result = FasterCSV.parse(file, options) { |row| }
    rescue FasterCSV::MalformedCSV
      @invalid = true
    end
  end

  def self.is_valid?
    !@invalid
  end    

  def self.parsed_result
    @parsed_result if self.valid?
  end

end
```

And then:

```
class CsvImporter
  include ActiveRecord::Validations

  validates_presence_of :file
  validate check_file_format

  # I assume you use the parsed result after the validations so in a before_save or something
  def do_your_parse_stuff
    here you would use FasterCSV::parsed_result
  end
...

  private

  def check_file_format
    FasterCSV::parse_and_validate(file)
    errors.add :file, "Malformed CSV! Please check syntax" unless FasterCSV::is_valid?
  end
end
```

In the above case, you might want to move stuff into a different class that takes care of communicating with FasterCSV and stashing away the parsed result, because I don't think my example is thread safe :)

Comment: If I'm reading FasterCSV docs correctly, it does not FasterCSV::parse doesn't allocate any memory for the parsed result if you give it a block (hence the `{ |row| }`). On the other hand, invalid files, at least on my case, are detected very early; usually on the first 2 lines. I don't actually mind the speed loss of parsing the file twice on this particular case. But thread safety is important.

Comment: Downvoted because your code sets instance variables on the class. If you have two CSV files, validating the second would destroy any ability to check the validity of the first.

Comment: @Phrogz You are right.. I kind of hinted at this with my last line.

Comment: @egarcia I wasn't afraid of memory usage, but with large or many files, you might notice.